# Does Saved Document Library Template become available to all subsites?

Tags: document-library, permissions, app

I have a test Site Collection.  I've added a document library to the root site and added content types to it.  When I save this Document Library as a template under Library Settings, this "App" becomes available to a subsite I created.

Will this work in a real environment?  If Permissions on the root site and a subsite are different, would this App still be available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your final question - the app (Document Library template) would still be available on the subsite.  Whether or not users can use the template you have created would be determined by their user permissions.

I believe the individual permission is 'manage lists', see [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels) for more info.  For [further reading this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fUnderstanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848) is also of use.  PLease note that there are multiple OOTB groups that have the 'manage lists' permission.  (A group is assigned a collection of permissions, which behave cumulatively).

[image: manage lists]